# read first 8 characters of text file with bash

Tags: file, bash, character

I would like to read only the first 8 characters of a text file and save it to a variable in bash. Is there a way to do this using just bash?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You can ask `head` to read a number of bytes.  For your particular case:

```
$ head -c 8 <file>
```

Or in a variable:

```
foo=$(head -c 8 <file>)
```

Answer (score 7):

in bash

```
help read
```

you'll see that you can :

```
read -r -n 8 variable < .the/file
```

If you want to read the first 8, independent of the separators,

```
IFS= read -r -n 8 variable < .the/file
```

But avoid using

```
.... | while IFS= read -r -n 8 variable
```

as, in bash, the parts after a "|" are run in a subshell: "variable" would only be changed in that subshell, and it's new value lost when returing to the present shell.

Comment: the last command set `IFS` to `''` just for the duration of the following command (here, the `read`)

Comment: Version 4 of `bash` introduces the `-N` option, which acts as `-n` but also ignores delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array in bash and select only first characters. Advanced Bash Scripting guide has good examples how to use arrays.

Comment: This is really only half an answer. How would you select just the first 8 characters from the array?

Comment: echo ${arrayZ[@]:1:2}   # two three

It's right there in ABS.

Granted, it's somewhat tedious. Alternative is to use loop.

BTW solution above using "head" is not using bash builtins only. "head" is an external program.